# How to solve $x_1+\cdots+x_p=30, \text{where }x_i+x_{i+1}=1, i \in \{1,2,...,p-1\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, systems-of-equations

## How to solve $x_1+\cdots+x_p=30, \text{where }x_i+x_{i+1}=1, i \in \{1,2,...,p-1\}$?

### ps.

Obviously we can get a special solution when $p=60, x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_{p-1}=0.5$. What I am confused about is how to find general solution in this case.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We claim that given $x_1 = k$, we can find the values of all $x_i, i\in[p]$. In particular, $x_i = \begin{cases} 
      k & x \text{ is odd} \\
      1-k & x \text{ is even}
   \end{cases}$

We will show this through induction.
For our bases cases, this is trivial: $x_1 = k$, and $x_1+x_2=1$, so $x_2=1-k$.

Given $x_n = k, x_{n+1} = 1-k$ by the inductive hypothesis, we know that $x_{n+1}+x_{n+2} = 1$, so $x_{n+2} = k$, then $x_{n+2}+x_{n+3} = 1$, so $x_{n+3} = 1-k$. Thus by weak induction with a step of size 2, we have shown our formula is true.

For even $p$, $\sum_{i=1}^p x_i = \frac{p}{2}(k)+\frac{p}{2}(1-k) = \frac{p}{2}(1) = \frac{p}{2}$, so the only even $p$ with a solution is $p = 60$, with any value of $k$ giving a new valid solution.

For odd $p$, $\sum_{i=1}^p x_i = \frac{p+1}{2}(k)+\frac{p-1}{2}(1-k) = \frac{p-1}{2}+k$, so given any $p$, simply construct the above series using $k = 30 - \frac{p-1}{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Let's solve for everything given $x_1$. We have
$$x_1+x_2=1\implies x_2=1-x_1$$
$$x_2+x_3=1\implies x_3=1-x_2=1-(1-x_1)=x_1,$$
et cetera. Can you find a general way to express $x_n$ in terms of $x_1$, and then use the given $x_1+\dots+x_p=30$ to solve for $(x_1,p)$?

Answer (score 0):

Consider that if $p$ is even
$$\sum_{i=1}^p x_i = \sum_{i=1}^\frac{p}{2} (x_{2i-1}+x_{2i})= \sum_{i=1}^\frac{p}{2} 1 = \frac{p}{2}.$$
Conversely if $p$ is odd
$$\sum_{i=1}^p x_i = x_1+\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} (x_{2i}+x_{2i+1})= x_1+\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} 1 = x_1+\frac{p-1}{2}.$$
So if $p$ is even we must have $p=60$ and $x_{2k-1}=m$, $x_{2k}=1-m$ for $k=1,\dots,\frac{p}{2}$ and any $m\in\mathbb{R}$. The odd case has arbitrary $p$ and all $x_i$ can be defined in terms of $p$. I will leave the details to you.